# Juniper - eBGP change next-hop on advertised routes

Tags: routing, bgp, juniper, juniper-mx

unable to advertise a route to ebgp peer and modify next-hop address. on receive router this can be resolved by configuring a import policy that matches on community and sets next hop to proper address; however, curious what i'm overlooking.

```
root@juniper.mx5# show logical-systems arouter protocols bgp       
accept-remote-nexthop;
local-address 10.10.200.46;
group external-65534 {
    traceoptions {
        file arouter-bgp-update;
        flag update;
        flag route;
        flag packets;
    }
    description root-ls;
    export internal-rtbh;
    peer-as 65534;
    neighbor 10.10.200.45;
}

group external-65422 {
    description arouter-ls;
    accept-remote-nexthop;
    local-address 10.10.200.45;
    peer-as 65422;
    neighbor 10.10.200.46;
}

root@juniper.mx5# show logical-systems arouter routing-options static | find 172.16.22.100 
route 172.16.22.100/32 {
    discard;
    tag 65422;
}


root@juniper.mx5# show logical-systems arouter policy-options policy-statement internal-rtbh 
from {
    protocol static;
    tag 65422;
}
then {
    local-preference 400;
    origin igp;
    community add no-export;
    next-hop 192.0.2.13;
    accept;
}


root@juniper.mx5# run show route logical-system arouter advertising-protocol bgp 10.10.200.45 extensive 

inet.0: 26 destinations, 26 routes (26 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
* 172.16.22.100/32 (1 entry, 1 announced)
 BGP group external-65534 type External
     Nexthop: Self
     Flags: Nexthop Change
     AS path: [65422] I
     Communities: no-export


root@juniper.mx5# run show route logical-system brouter receive-protocol bgp 10.10.200.46 extensive 

inet.0: 40 destinations, 40 routes (40 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
* 172.16.22.100/32 (1 entry, 1 announced)
     Accepted
     Nexthop: 10.10.200.46
     AS path: 65422 I
     Communities: no-export
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way eBGP works is that it will always set the next-hop to the directly connected address of the sending router (except for multihop sessions or when the original next-hop is in the same subnet). As you can see in your output the router is sending the route with `Nexthop: Self`, not with the nexthop you have configured. You can find the decision tree for next-hop generation in the [BGP RFC4271](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#section-5.1.3)

As a workaround you could change the session to use eBGP multihop, which has a `no-nexthop-change` [option](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/reference/configuration-statement/no-nexthop-change-protocols-bgp-multihop.html):

```
set protocols bgp group external-65534 multihop no-nexthop-change
```

Using [eBGP multihop](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos11.4/topics/concept/bgp-multihop-understanding.html) has other drawbacks like no fast external failover.

Normally you would just leave the next-hop unchanged and set a BGP community. The receiver would then set the correct next-hop by matching the community. That's how [remote triggered blackholing (RTBH)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5635) works between eBGP peers.